# How to enable access control on mongos

Tags: mongodb

I've tried to start my mongos instance with access control using the --auth option but I get `Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--auth'`. How do I require authentication to connect to the mongos instance?

edit: I'm using `mongos --configdb config/192.168.1.69:27017 --bind_ip=192.168.1.67 --fork --syslog` to start mongos

Comment: Please provide your full command (without password) and the config file.

Comment: Added in original post

Comment: You have to configure security on each shard/config server. Have a look at this one: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-sharded-cluster/index.html (for existing cluster) or https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-sharded-cluster-with-keyfile-access-control/ (for new cluster)

Comment: Ok so regular user authorization does not work in a sharded cluster?

Comment: It does. However, the mongos instance does not store any user data/roles. Users have to be defined in config server, then you can use them for authentication.